# Visual C++ Test project doesn't display standard output

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, c++-cli, stdout

I created a Visual C++ test project which contains printf statements. Unfortunately, I can't find a method to view the output of this. It isn't included in the output window. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect standard output to a file and open this file in some auto-refreshing viewer.

***UPDATE:***
Here are two ways to redirect standard output to a file, that I found:

1. cmd way: `C:\Test>myWinApp.exe > log.txt`
2. powershell way: `PS C:\Test> .\myWinApp.exe 2>&1 | out-file log.txt`

If you want to view the output in real time, you can open log.txt in some file viewer with auto-refreshing option. [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087821/windows-winxp-cmd-how-to-pipe-the-output-of-a-script-to-a-log-file-and-display-o/5969089#5969089)