# Windows/WinXP CMD: How to pipe the output of a script to a log file AND display output?

Tags: logging, cmd, stdout, pipe

I'm running python scripts from cmd.  I am currently piping the output of the script to a log file that I specify.  However, I would also like to be able to visually monitor the progress of the execution by watching output scroll.

I'm piping to a log file because the window buffer is not sufficiently long to contain the entire log.  However, the only way to get instant feedback of the current state of the execution is to keep refreshing the log file by opening it.

Can you suggest a better way to solve my problem?  Ideally I'd like to pipe output to a file and display in cmd while it executes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tee command from cygwin...

Or it is very easy to implement (at least basic version) of tee command yourself.

tee usage:
`your_command | tee outfile.txt #overwrites file 

 your_command | tee -a outfile.txt #overwrites file`
To capture stderr as well as stdout, use
`your_command 2>&1 | tee [-a] outfile.txt`

Comment: `tee` is the right solution, but this would be a better answer if you at least showed an example of how to use it to answer the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some file viewer with autorefreshing option. Have a look at this questions from *superuser.com*:
[Text / log editor with auto-refresh support](https://superuser.com/questions/106073/text-log-editor-with-auto-refresh-support)
[Log viewer on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/153/log-viewer-on-windows)